# NA in subsetter - Inconsistent behavior

Tags: r

Consider the following:

```
seq(from=10,to=30)[c(4,8)]
[1] 13 17

seq(from=10,to=30)[c(NA,8)]
[1] NA 17

seq(from=10,to=30)[c(NA,NA)]
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

To me the result of the latter is inconsistent with how the other two examples are handled by R and has cost me quite unpleasant debugging pains.

Might this be considered a bug?

Comment: A bug, no.  None of the `seq(10, 30)` is `NA`. `[` is an extraction function.  The `NA` you are trying to extract are not present in the sequence.

Comment: Try `seq(from=10,to=30)[c(TRUE, FALSE)]` and see what you get.

Comment: Or try `(10:30)[NA]` to see what you get.  `R`'s rules about dealing with `NA` are quite explicit and are in fact consistent.

Comment: I don't get that. `(10:30)[c(NA,8)]` might be paraphrased into: "Return the 'not applicable' and 8th element", so why is "return the 'not applicable' element twice" not returning `c(NA,NA)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it is a bug - I suspect that depends on your point of view, but it is a subtlety of how indexing works. The quick solution is to change your third example to:

```
seq(from=10,to=30)[as.numeric(c(NA,NA))]
```

The reason is that `c(NA,NA)` is a logical vector, so the logical subsetting (which involves recycling the vector) is used, whereas having at least one non-NA causes the vector to be promoted to an integer vector. Likewise this could be implemented as:

```
seq(from=10,to=30)[c(NA_integer_,NA_integer_)]
```

See `?'['` for specifics of indexing if you're not familiar with them.

Comment: That makes it very clear - I had not appreciated the type difference the subsetting vector is subject to and always thought about `NA` as a kind of neutral type. Thank you very much.