# Indexing integer vector with NA

Tags: r, indexing, subset, na

I have problems understanding this. I have an integer vector of length 5:

```
x <- 1:5
```

If I index it with a single `NA`, the result is of length 5:

```
x[NA] 
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA
```

My first idea was that R checks whether 1-5 is `NA` but

```
x <- c(NA, 2, 4)
x[NA] 
# NA NA NA.
```

So this cannot be the solution. My second approach is that `x[NA]` is indexing but then I do not understand

1. Why this gives me five `NA's`
2. What NA as an index means. `x[1]` gives you the first value but what should be the result of `x[NA]`?

Comment: What do you expect as output?

Comment: See [this similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23406124/na-in-subsetter-inconsistent-behavior)

Comment: @zx8754: So R checks whether 1 is at position NA but this is NA since there is no position NA. Now it goes to the next value 2 here is the same problem and so on?

Comment: Did you read `help("[")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare your code:

```
> x <- 1:5; x[NA] 
[1] NA NA NA NA NA
```

with

```
> x <- 1:5; x[NA_integer_] 
[1] NA
```

In the first case, `NA` is of type logical (`class(NA)` shows), whereas in the second it's an integer. From `?"["` you can see that in the case of `i` being logical, it is recycled to the length of `x`:

> For [-indexing only: i, j, ... can be logical vectors, indicating
>   elements/slices to select. Such vectors are recycled if necessary to
>   match the corresponding extent. i, j, ... can also be negative
>   integers, indicating elements/slices to leave out of the selection.