# How does subsetting with NA work?

Tags: r, subset, na

Can someone please answer in layman terms how indexing (subsetting) with `NA` works. Even though there are some answers from google, I would like to understand it better in simple terms.

When indexing a vector (of length > 1) using a single `NA`, why does it yield five missing values?

```
> x <- 1:5
> x[NA]
[1] NA NA NA NA NA
```

Comment: Because there are some things in R that have "always been", even if they don't necessarily make sense in current perspectives given modern expectations of vectors, indexing, etc. (To me, this behavior is not intuitive, I have just accepted it as "the way it is with R".)

Comment: Great question. I have never been confronted with this. I think if you subset with NA there is always something broken :-) that needs to be catched.

Comment: Not necessarily "broken", @AndreElrico! I have plenty of data where `NA` is perfectly meaningful and intentionally retained. It's the equivalent of SQL's `null`. There are times where I knowingly have an `NA` in an index vector and subset based on it, knowing (relying on, even) that it will give me an `NA` in that location. (In that case, though, it's typically `NA_integer_` and not the elusive `logical` that defaults with `[NA]`.)

Comment: Related dupe-oids: [Why does xNA yield an NA vector the same length as x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240241/why-does-xna-yield-an-na-vector-the-same-length-as-x?noredirect=1&lq=1); [Indexing with NA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38991967/indexing-with-na); [NA in subsetter - Inconsistent behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23406124/na-in-subsetter-inconsistent-behavior?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 9):

From `help("[")`:

> When extracting, a numerical, logical or character NA index picks an
>   unknown element and so returns NA in the corresponding element of a
>   logical, integer, numeric, complex or character result, and NULL for a
>   list.

What does "corresponding element" mean? This can be understood if you know about recycling of vector elements. `x[NA]` (this is a logical `NA` per default) in your example is actually "interpreted" as `x[c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)]` since logical indices are recycled. So, each element of `x` has a corresponding `NA` during subsetting and thus (per the quote above) `NA` is returned for each element of `x`. In layman's language: For each element of `x` we don't know if we want it. Thus an unknown value is returned for each element.

As @r2evans points out: `x[NA_integer_]` returns only one `NA` because integer indices are not recycled. In layman's language: We want one value but don't know which one. Thus, one unknown value is returned.

Comment: Ahhhh ... so it might make *more* sense to view the differences between `x[NA]` and `x[NA_integer_]`, where the first is actually class `logical`, where `x[T]` and `x[F]` behavior (returning 5 elements) actually makes sense. Nice, Roland.

Comment: @r2evans highly valuable comment.

Comment: This is what made sense to me. Let me know if I am correct. Logical vectors get recycled. So NA gets recycled for 5 times. With each NA there is an associated NA value in x. SO 5 NA is returned for each of 5 NA in x.

Comment: @r2evans `x[F]` doesn't return 5 elements but `integer(0)` (in this case)

Comment: Another puzzle : `names(x) <- NA; identical(names(x)[1],NA_character_); x[NA_character_]`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper, you're right ... I hastily said `x[F]` recycled when it doesn't. (hang-head-low). Uh, yeah, R's dealing with vectors and logicals and stuff can sometimes seem inconsistent or counter-intuitive ... but I'm guessing it makes sense to *somebody* and/or from a certain *perspective*. In retrospect, it makes perfect sense to me that `x[F]` returns `integer(0)`: if `x[c(T,F,F,...)]` returns just the first element, then I would expect `x[c(F,F,F,...)]` to return *no* elements ... so even if it *is* recycling, it makes sense.